# WIA: "There is no application registered for this event" repeatedly

Tags: windows, windows-vista, services, webcam

I have a weird and annoying issue on my computer. I have an old USB webcam plugged into my machine and it works fine... apart from one thing. If someone presses the button on the webcam, I get the following error message in Windows:

> Windows Image Acquisition Service: There is no application registered for this event.

I click 'Ok', but the pop-up keeps appearing. Over and over. It never goes away.

I restart the WIA service. I unplugged and replug the webcam, but every time this annoying window appears.

I've managed to make it stop in the past, but I can't remember how.

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that starting a program that uses the WIA service is enough to put this message at bay. (I opened up Photoshop.) There you go!